# C# Application Domain Private bin Path Update

Tags: c#, appdomain

does anyone know if it is possible to change the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath for the current application domain? or does this only affect future appdomain instances..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Library says

Changing the properties of an AppDomainSetup instance does not affect any existing AppDomain. It can affect only the creation of a new AppDomain, when the CreateDomain method is called with the AppDomainSetup instance as a parameter.

When I needed this, started my app with an empty AppDomain that sets up the stage for the others.
Do you need more info on this?